# If I want to use a third party library, should I build it statically or dynamically?

Tags: c++, build, dependency-management

I am starting a project to make some Python bindings around an existing C++ library. I'll then use those bindings as part of another project.

I have cloned the existing library and am uncertain of the way forward from here. Should I copy and paste all of the header and cpp files into my own project and just `include` them?

Or should I use the existing repo's instructions to build the code, and then somehow import it into a new project? Looking at the readme, (if this is the correct way forward) I have the option to either build dynamically or statically. Is one better than the other in the context of using as a third party `include`?

I am familiar with C++ in syntax only. All of the under-the-hood stuff of building and compiling is very confusing to me, although I am starting to learn at least some of the vocabulary. Any answer that takes this into account is greatly appreciated.

#### My Research:

From what I can tell, no matter what path I take, I need to somehow edit CMakeLists.txt to tell my IDE where to find the third party library files I want to include. I can't tell if these are supposed to be the source files from the cloned repos, or some other type of file from compiling the source.

I'm looking specifically at thes CMake calls:

- `add_library`
- `include_directories`
- `link_directories`
- `target_link_libraries`

However, the documentation isn't that great for beginners. It also doesn't answer the question as to whether I should build the third party library or just use the source code files...

Comment: On Windows I say usually dynamically and create an installer package for your application which bundles everything  (applications, runtime files, dlls, assets ...) in 1 executable.

Comment: ***Or should I use the existing repo's instructions to build the code,*** I usually do that. However it depends on the project. Just pulling source code from some library into your code can be easy to nearly impossible and if you do so you can have a lot of work updating in the future when this library project has a bug fix.

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: @WBuck it is Adobe's XMP SDK. I found some libraries with bindings that only apparently work on Linux.